# How to show the flutter timepicker in 12 hours format with AM PM selector

Tags: flutter, dart, timepicker

I want to use the Flutter timepicker in 12 hour format with AM/PM selector, but Flutter only shows me the 24 hours format.

I want to get this format:
[image]

But flutter only shows me this format:
[image]

This is my code:

```
_selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
  TimeOfDay picked = await showTimePicker(
    context: context,
    initialTime: TimeOfDay(hour: 12, minute: 00),
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
      return MediaQuery(
        data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: false),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This should show you what you want

```
RaisedButton(
  child: Text('Show Time Picker'),
  onPressed: () async => await showTimePicker(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
      return MediaQuery(
        data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: false),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  ),
),
```

Comment: The source code of this answer is similar to the original one. I have tried but do not work.

Answer (score 5):

just use format() method to get AM,PM what you required.

```
final TimeOfDay picked = await showTimePicker(
  context: context,
  initialTime: timeStart,
);
print(picked.format(context));    // 8:15 PM
```

Answer (score 3):

you were used showTimePicker()
and in this you assign initialTime value than it will consider 24 hour format
but if you want 12 hour format follow this way

i make a function this will called from button's onTap : (){} method

myFunction

```
Future<TimeOfDay?> getTime({
  required BuildContext context,
  String? title,
  TimeOfDay? initialTime,
  String? cancelText,
  String? confirmText,
}) async {
  TimeOfDay? time = await showTimePicker(
    initialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.dial,
    context: context,
    initialTime: initialTime ?? TimeOfDay.now(),
    cancelText: cancelText ?? "Cancel",
    confirmText: confirmText ?? "Save",
    helpText: title ?? "Select time",
    builder: (context, Widget? child) {
      return MediaQuery(
        data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: false),
        child: child!,
      );
    },
  );

  return time;
}
```

here inside builder applied MediaQuery method and MediaQuery will take data ,
so, here you need to assign as
data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: false),

and you will get 12 hour format Time

if you like watch full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('getTime'),
              onPressed: () async {
                TimeOfDay? time = await getTime(
                  context: context,
                  title: "Select Your Time",
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<TimeOfDay?> getTime({
  required BuildContext context,
  String? title,
  TimeOfDay? initialTime,
  String? cancelText,
  String? confirmText,
}) async {
  TimeOfDay? time = await showTimePicker(
    initialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.dial,
    context: context,
    initialTime: initialTime ?? TimeOfDay.now(),
    cancelText: cancelText ?? "Cancel",
    confirmText: confirmText ?? "Save",
    helpText: title ?? "Select time",
    builder: (context, Widget? child) {
      return MediaQuery(
        data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: false),
        child: child!,
      );
    },
  );

  return time;
}
```

[image]

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Below snippet, I found form [Flutter Github Issues](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54839)

```
await showTimePicker(
          initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
          context: context,
          builder: (context, child) {
            final Widget mediaQueryWrapper = MediaQuery(
              data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
                alwaysUse24HourFormat: false,
              ),
              child: child,
            );
            // A hack to use the es_US dateTimeFormat value.
            if (Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode == 'es') {
              return Localizations.override(
                context: context,
                locale: Locale('es', 'US'),
                child: mediaQueryWrapper,
              );
            }
            return mediaQueryWrapper;
          },
        );
```

> Time Picker is picking format **based on locale**. Above code is tweaking
> country of Locale to US because US has 12 hours of time format.
> Instead of "es" use language code in which you are getting problem.

All credit goes to person who posted solution in above mentioned link. I am reposting it here so, people can find that solution easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use can this lib [Flutter DatePicker](https://github.com/Realank/flutter_datetime_picker)

Code to show 12 hours format with AM/PM:

```
onTap: (){
    DatePicker.showTime12hPicker(context,
        showTitleActions: true,
        onConfirm: (date) {
          _endTimeController.text = DateFormat.jm().format(date);
        }, locale: LocaleType.en);
  },
```

And see result below:

[image]