# How can I get the TimePicker in Flutter to be AM/PM?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is not a dupe of [How to show the flutter timepicker in 12 hours format with AM PM selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61146334/how-to-show-the-flutter-timepicker-in-12-hours-format-with-am-pm-selector), because my issue is different and the presented solution of an added mediaquery did not help at all.

So my issue is that the datetimepicker shows me 24h in a circle, from 00 to 00, see picture: [image: bleh who would prefer a 24h analog clock, horrible!]

How do I change this to be a 12h clock? Even if i can't reasonably change it to am/pm, how can I get the clock that shows 2 rings of 0-12 and 12-0[image: this would also be ok!]

Any help is welcome! Now to my code

```dart
  _selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
    final TimeOfDay? timeOfDay = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: selectedTime,
      initialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.dial,
    );
    if (timeOfDay != null && timeOfDay != selectedTime) {
      setState(() {
        selectedTime = timeOfDay;
      });
    }
  }
```

It is called upon an InkWell press.

Comment: Tried your provided code. It shows AM PM format in my Device.

Comment: @Dharmendra odd